# Scala - Future List first completed with condition

Tags: list, scala, conditional-statements, future

I have a list of Futures and I want to get the first one completed with a certain condition. 
Here is an example of a possible code:

```
val futureList: Future[List[T]] = l map (c => c.functionWithFuture())
val data = for {
           c <- futureList
           }yield c
data onSuccess {
  case x => (x filter (d=> d.condition)).head
}
```

But it's not efficient, because I'll take only one element of the list, but computed all of them with a lot of latency.

I know `firstCompletedOf` but it's not what I'm searching.

(Sorry for my bad English.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a `Promise` and calling `trySuccess` on it as soon as a future that satisfies the condition completes. The first to call `trySuccess` will complete the future, the following ones will have no effect (as opposed to calling `success`, which can only be called once on a `Promise`).

Keep in mind that if no future in the list satisfies the condition, you will **never** have a result, i.e. the promise future will never complete.

```
import scala.concurrent.{ Await, Future, Promise }
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.util.Random

def condition(x: Int) = x > 50

val futures = (1 to 10) map (x => Future {
  // wait a random number of ms between 0 and 1000
  Thread.sleep(Random.nextInt(1000))
  // return a random number < 100
  Random.nextInt(100)
})

val p = Promise[Int]()
// the first one that satisfies the condition completes the promise
futures foreach { _ filter condition foreach p.trySuccess }
val result = p.future

// Watch out: the promise could never be fulfilled if all the futures are <=50
println("The first completed future that satisfies x>50 is: " + Await.result(result, 10.seconds))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! But does this solution force the first Future completed to be filtered ? Aren't we just doing this: wait for the first Future completed, check it and then the second one ?

Comment: No, take a look at future.filter(), it's basically a `map` transformation that trows an exception if the condition doesn't hold. It requires an execution context. Operations on future are *never* blocking unless you call Await.result(future, t) :)

Comment: let me add that it's the same for `foreach`, you're basically registering a callback. You can check it by setting a longer sleep in the future code and printing something after the  `futures foreach ...` line, you'll notice it gets printed immediately

Comment: Ok, perfect! It seems that it works. Thanks a lot for your help!