# Another scala Futures composition puzzler

Tags: scala, concurrent.futures

I am migrating code from a synchronous to an async style. The problem is fairly simple: call a series of functions, and stop with the first one to return a non-error result (returning that value, otherwise the last computed value). I started with:

```
def find(fs: Seq[Function0[Int]], result: Int = -1): Int = {
  if (fs.isEmpty) result
  else {
    val res = fs.head()
    if (res != 0) res
    else find(fs.tail, res)
  }
}
```

However, if the functions become async, (i.e. return Future[Int]) I can't get the right invocation. For example,

```
def ffind(ffs: Seq[Function0[Future[Int]]], result: Future[Int] = Future { -1 }): Future[Int] = {
  if (ffs.isEmpty) result
  else ffind(ffs.tail, ffs.head())
}
```

works great, but it evaluates all the functions, regardless of return value. But something like:

```
def findBad(ffs: Seq[Function0[Future[Int]]], result: Future[Int] = Future { -1 }): Future[Int] = {
  if (ffs.isEmpty) result
  else {
      ffs.head() map { res =>
        if (res != 0) res
        else findBad(ffs.tail, Future(res))
      }
   }
}
```

doesn't type-check. Any suggestions? We can suppose that each call of a function is expensive, so none should be called twice, nor any after the first 'successful' call in the sequence. TIA

Comment: hi, is this resolved?

Comment: yes, sorry I failed to update the question, merely upvoting the answer. Much appreciated!

Comment: I'm just cleaning up because I'm obsessive-compulsive so I'm wondering if my answer resolved your problem, in which case you should mark it as accepted, or it was insufficient, in which case I will delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's why it doesn't type-check: `findBad` returns a `Future[Int]`, but mapping `res` into an invocation of `findBad` would result in a `Future[Future[Int]]`. You need to change `map` into `flatMap`. Note that now you also need to wrap `res` from the first condition (if res != 0) into a `Future` too, so that both branches return a `Future`. Here's the code:

```
ffs.head() flatMap { res =>
  if (res != 0) Future.succesful(res)
  else findBad(ffs.tail, Future(res))
}
```

BTW if you want to run them all and return whichever completes first, disregarding all the rest, then it's a bit different problem (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35961330/scala-future-list-first-completed-with-condition)), but you say that each function call is expensive so I doubt that's what you are trying to do.

Comment: Never use `Future.apply` for constants, that's what `Future.successful` is designed for. The `Future(res)` will create additional unnecessary work, as it gets scheduled and executed as if the result is not known. There's even an `implicit ex: ExecutionContext` required in the signature.

Comment: I thought of this just as I posted, but in this case I think the difference is trivial in practice so I didn't bother editing. But OK, point taken, will modify.